# How to display data via textfield in Table Footer in JasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a table structure like this.

```
Table Header
    some code
Table Detail
    Some Values
Table Footer
    Some Values
```

Moreover, I want to add that I have add extra cells in table footer as per my requirement and I am putting these textfields in that cell in table footer.

Now  the textfields which I have put into table header section works perfectly and shows data but the textfields which I put in Table Footer(even the same as table header section) are showing the data of the last bean only. I have almost 25 beans. So it is only showing the data of 25th bean in all 25 page in table footer section.

Comment: What have you tried? And why did it not work? Welcome to StackOverflow. We try to solve technical problems here but we won't write the code for you. Please try to solve the problem yourself and when you get into trouble come again and ask a specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, It will, because all your 25 beans will iterate through in your **Detail Band**, while you reach at **footer** it will only have data of last(here 25th) bean, so it will print the data of your last bean.

You should add more bands (Groups) between *Table Header* and *Table footer* (Group Header above Detail Band and Group Footer below Detail Band) that Print your bean data in their ***Group Header*** and ***Group Footer*** bands.

```
Table Header
    some code
Group Header  <------------------Print your Header value here(Group according to some criteria)
    Some code

Table Detail
    Some Values

Group Footer  <------------------ Print your footer value here(Group according to some criteria)
    Some Values
Table Footer
    Some Values
```

I think that will print all your bean data and not only last beans data.